# About OpenCL's clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

Say I have the following code:

```
size_t globalSize = 4294967295; // (2^(32))-1
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalSize, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Doesn't this mean that I want the kernel to be executed 4294967295 times and that OpenCL will decide the most efficient workgroup size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially yes, although you may want to note a few things:

- Note that the argument following `&globalSize` is a `NULL` pointer, not the integer value 0, as the parameter is declared as `const size_t *local_work_size.
- It won't necessarily be *the most efficient* workgroup size in all cases; implementations may not be able to predict that fully accurately. They should pick an appropriate/reasonable size, however.
- Implementations may have runtime limits which may cause the kernel execution to be aborted prematurely, or the device may not support preemption, potentially causing the system to freeze. Gigantic work sizes like that may therefore not be ideal.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You answered my question.

Comment: In the case of an odd or prime global work size, the runtime likely won't run an efficient work group size. Powers of two and/or multiples of 64 work better. You can use a larger-than-needed global size, pass in an argument for the desired size, and add a conditional to the kernel to skip over the few that are larger. The performance gain is worth the overhead.